# Adding Skype for Business scope to v2.0 Azure app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

I am creating a v2.0 application via the new [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) (`apps.dev.microsoft.com`) and I can't find where to add scopes for other non-Graph APIs. Specifically Skype for Business.

In the classic Azure portal, i had access to this screen which allowed me to add scopes for other APIs:

[image]

In the new Application Registration Portal, the only place I see to add scopes is here:

[image]

and Skype for Business is not an option there.

How do I add the Skype for Business scope to v2.0 apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Skype for Business APIs (Web SDK, UCMA, UCWA, etc.) currently do not support the [v2 Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview).

At the moment the majority of Microsoft APIs [do not support the v2 Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-services-and-apis). Given the enormous legacy of APIs Microsoft supports, there unfortunately isn't an exhaustive list. Generally, unless the API documentation expressly states support for the v2 Endpoint or Converged Authentication it means you'll need to use the v1 Endpoint.

One aside on permissions with the v2 Endpoint. With the v1 Endpoint you requests access by "resource" and pre-defined the permissions you required within the Azure Portal. The v2 Endpoint no longer uses resources however; it now uses "scopes" that are dynamically defined during the authentication workflow. For more details see [Scopes, not resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#scopes-not-resources).

I'd recommend adding this request to the [UserVoice site](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/filters/top?category_id=160794). This will help ensure this remains on product teams radar going forward.

Comment: thank you for the response. i've added the request to UserVoice [(link to request)](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32536252-add-support-on-v2-0-applications-for-skype-for-bus).